# AWS + Ansible Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have 50 Ubuntu severs in AWS. Now I am planning to install Ngnix to the 50 servers using Ansible. For this case, I have created an Ansible Master server and playbook. But how can I connect to the destination servers, it is not possible to add SSH keys individually to these 50 servers, so I need to automate the task. I need to add `id_rsa_pub` from Ansible Master to `authorized_keys` on the destination servers. But as you now AWS server authentication id done by default using SSH Keys files. So how can I specify the key file for the initial authentication, that is `ssh_copy_id` section.

Comment: Could you post the current version of your playbook? I don't seem to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your inventory ini file you can use this var:

```
[group1]
HOST A
HOST B

[group2]
HOST C
HOST D

[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=RELATIVE_PATH_TO_KEY_FILE
```

Or you can use different keys per each group by using

```
[group1]
HOST A
HOST B

[group2]
HOST C
HOST D

[group1:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=RELATIVE_PATH_TO_KEY_FILE_GROUP1


[group2:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=RELATIVE_PATH_TO_KEY_FILE_GROUP2
```

This key file will be used for the SSH connection to the hosts.
Now the SSH connection can be made and then run the commands you wanted in the hosts.